# How do i implement an svg file in an HTML code

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple user webpage  and I came across a svg file as an image.
So I am not sure if I am to use it as the normal  tag in HTML or otherwise.
Any form of help will be appreciated

Comment: you can insert like any HTML tag <svg></svg> or you can use <img src="./path.svg" />

Answer (score 3):

Just like a normal image, you can set the source of an `img` tag to the path of your svg:

```
<img src="picture.svg" width="100" height="200" />
```

However, if you are depending on adding custom CSS to the svg, you cannot use an `img` tag. Then you have to add the svg code directly to your HTML document:

```
<body>
    <svg class="my-svg">
      <rect width="300" height="100" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

```
.my-svg rect {
  fill: red
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: black;
}
```